# Why passing arguments to an interface does not lead to an error?

Tags: interfaces

I am studying a sample contract and found the interface to be defined and declared as:

```
interface IUniswapV2Router02 is IUniswapV2Router01 {
    function removeLiquidityETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
        address token,
        uint liquidity,
        ...
    ) external returns (uint amountETH);
}
```

Within the contract, this interface is used seldom as

```
...
IUniswapV2Router02 public immutable uniswapV2Router;
...

constructor () public {
    _rOwned[_msgSender()] = _rTotal;
    IUniswapV2Router02 _uniswapV2Router = IUniswapV2Router02(0x10ED43C718714eb63d5aA57B78B54704E256024E);
        // Create a uniswap pair for this new token
...
```

What I find hard to understand is that how is an argument (the address `0x10ED43C718714eb63d5aA57B78B54704E256024E`) being passed to the interface ? Are interfaces supposed to allow this ?

Comment: Not sure i understand your question, but yeah, `interface(yourContractAddress)` is a way to tell your contract that whatever is at `yourContractAddress` is compatible with `interface` and you can use it to interact with this contract. That's kinda the main use of interfaces tbf

Answer (score 0):

This is how it is supposed to work. In the example above, you are not calling any methods in the interface contract. This is interpreted as telling EVM to create an instance (called _uniswapV2Router) with the same functions/variables of the interface at contract in address X. Then you will be able to interact with contract using the instance.